# Show new Flag's with views

Tags: views, flags

is it possible to get the amount of "new flags" in views? Like the "new comments" field. For example a user's article was flagged 2 times. After his login he should see in a view: "2 new flaggs on your article".

Drupal 7;
Views 3; Flag 7.x-3.2

thanks for ur help!
lolhonk

Answer (score 1):

So add relationship "your_flag"

and in **Sort criteria** delete default **Content: Post date (desc)**

and add Flags: **Flagged time**

PS maybe i don't understand you, why you need in views this show? not in teaser node?